# '{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Record<string, any>'

Tags: typescript, subtype

I find a few questions already like this. But I don't know how to fixed more alike typscript style. I don't want to use 'as'.

These are my some questions example:

First Error: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.

```
function copy<T extends Record<string, any>>(target: T): T {
  const res: T = {} // Error 1: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.

  Object.keys(target).forEach(key => {
    if (typeof target[key] === 'object') res[key] = copy(target[key])
    else if (typeof target[key] === 'string') res[key] = target[key];
  });

  return res
}
```

Second Error: Type 'Record<string, any>' is not assignable to type 'T'

```
function copy<T extends Record<string, any>>(target: T): T {
  const res: Record<string, any> = {};

  Object.keys(target).forEach(key => {
    if (typeof target[key] === 'object') res[key] = copy(target[key])
    else if (typeof target[key] === 'string') res[key] = target[key];
  });

  return res // Type 'Record<string, any>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
}
```

And I use 'as' to fixed, see: [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQAQyQBwJ4B4AqqApgB5xFQAmAzqgEpEYBOlu1cTCUA5gDSoBDKNgB8IgBRwBTbkTgAuVPgCUiwgG9QqdCnaomRaoobNW7Tj35DRqALyp1AXwDcoLagDyAIwBWjOAB0ANZE2NSS0rJwygFgSEwAogIwABbiIdh2Ig7u2ghgqJLYmERIBVIycgDaGQC6drb2AORIvv5NyvqGNaH19hg4EZVwPdi1yrnEADbURKj5hXDFpeWR1XUNzeZc3B1d1KN9qBVRh64g2o7K5+4GcBBMaAa0ArT4545AA)

```
function copy<T extends Record<string, any>>(target: T): T {
  const res: Record<string, any> = {};

  Object.keys(target).forEach(key => {
    if (typeof target[key] === 'object') res[key] = copy(target[key])
    else if (typeof target[key] === 'string') res[key] = target[key];
  });

  return res as T;
}
```

Do somebody have other ways to solve this? Or how can I pass T type to function and want to return T Type, T need extends object or Record.

Answer (score 0):

These are both essentially the same problem. You know that T looks like a Record, but you don't know anything else about it, so initializing it with {} is not safe, and since TypeScript can't guarantee it, it doesn't let you do it.

It's like having a class `Cat` and trying to initialize it with an instance of a class `Animal` ... you know that it is an Animal, but that's not enough to properly initialize a Cat.

Specifically, for your first error you are trying to initialize a Cat with an instance of Animal, and for your second error, you have created an Animal and you're trying to return it as a Cat.

Here's an example with your `copy` that would fail if it was permitted.

```
let counter = 0;
class MyClass implements Record<string, any> {
  public instanceNumber: number;
  constructor() {
    console.log("Reporting to central command, new MyClass")
    this.instanceNumber = counter++;
  }

  printInstanceNumber() {
    console.log(`I am ${this.instanceNumber}`);
  }
}

function copy<T extends Record<string, any>>(target: T): T {
  const res: Record<string, any> = {};
  Object.keys(target).forEach(key => {
    if (typeof target[key] === 'object') res[key] = copy(target[key])
    else if (typeof target[key] === 'string') res[key] = target[key];
    else if (typeof target[key] === 'number') res[key] = target[key];
  });
  return res as T;
}

const originalInstance = new MyClass();

const myCopy = copy(originalInstance);

// Has the wrong instance number...
console.log("original instanceNumber:", originalInstance.instanceNumber); // 0
console.log("copied instanceNumber:", myCopy.instanceNumber); // 0

// And crashes, no printInstanceNumber
originalInstance.printInstanceNumber(); // works
myCopy.printInstanceNumber(); // crashes, myCopy.printInstanceNumber is not a function
```

Comment: thank you so much for your kinds word. But I want to know how to initialize the 'res' or how to return a correct type for typescript. This example of 'copy function' just is a simple copy demo and maybe it does not perform well.